# React JS Frontend with DRF backend authentication

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Have developed a pretty decent API utilizing Django and Django Rest Framework to make my data available for consumption. Decided to build a React JS front end to be a little more dynamic than the standard Django templates. I have numerous views within DRF which work fine, I'm able to make calls against them and get or post to them no problem. Currently I'm working on implementing a login capability for the React frontend so that users will be given access to a couple protected views and will be presented with information relevant to them.

Maybe I'm not understanding what is supposed to be happening, web development isn't exactly my area of expertise. Have referenced the Django documentation a bunch trying to understand sessions and session authentication. I have a 'login' view which is taking a username and password provided to it, searching for a related 'User' record based off of the username and attempting to leverage the django.contrib.auth login method; this all seems to be working, the user is getting authenticated. After this step, I'm pretty much completely lost as to what is supposed to happen.

In my React component, I've attempted sending the username as a 'session' attribute in the header, I've tried including the csrftoken in the headers, I've tried to just enable 'withCredentials' in the callout. Really not sure what I'm supposed to be doing here. Is my login view supposed to be returning some attribute that I would then store in the react components to include in calls to protected views?

Been stuck on this for a while and am getting lost in reading documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You must to use token authentication not session. You will use session authentication only when you login to the django admin.  From react you will use token

Comment: Drf documentation supports session authentication, and from what I was seeing this is a more secure design pattern than using token authentication. Is there a reason I can’t use session authentication? Documentation link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication